# Why can only one player move at a time Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I'm trying to add two players to my pygame game yet only one of them seems to be able to move at a time. They can both move independently when the other player.move is removed. If I remove one player.move, the one that wasn't removed can move but if I keep both player.move's, then the one I put first is the only one able to move. Sorry if the code is bad, it's my first time trying classes and all. Thanks in advance.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

game_over = False
screen_width = 1680
screen_height = 1050
fps = 60
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

jumping = False
player_x = 0
player_y = screen_height - 100
player2_x = screen_width - 100
player2_y = screen_height - 100
gravity = 0.2

class Player:

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, icon, direction_x, direction_y, speed, weight, x_acc, y_acc, jumping, start_y, p_number):
        self.icon = pygame.image.load(icon)
        self.icon = pygame.transform.scale(self.icon, (width, height))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.direction_x = direction_x
        self.direction_y = direction_y
        self.speed = speed
        self.weight = weight
        self.x_acc = x_acc
        self.y_acc = y_acc
        self.jumping = jumping
        self.start_y = start_y
        self.p_number = p_number


    def move(self):
        global game_over
        for event in pygame.event.get():            
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if self.p_number == 1:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == ord("w"):
                        self.direction_y = 1                        
                    elif event.key == ord("s"):
                        self.direction_y = -1                        
                    elif event.key == ord("d"):
                        self.direction_x = -1
                    elif event.key == ord("a"):
                        self.direction_x = 1
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        game_over = True
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    self.direction_y = 0
                    self.direction_x = 0
            if self.p_number == 2:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        self.direction_y = 1                        
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.direction_y = -1                        
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.direction_x = -1
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.direction_x = 1
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        game_over = True
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    self.direction_y = 0
                    self.direction_x = 0

    def update(self):
        #if self.direction_y < 0:
            #self.y += self.speed
        if self.direction_x > 0:
            self.x -= self.speed
        elif self.direction_x < 0:
            self.x += self.speed

    def jump(self, gravity):
        if self.direction_y > 0:
            if self.y == self.start_y:
                self.y_acc = -20
                self.jumping = True

        if self.jumping:
            self.y_acc += gravity * self.weight
            self.y += self.y_acc
            if self.y_acc == 19:
                self.jumping = False

player1 = Player(player_x, player_y, 100, 100, "Icon.png", 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, False, player_y, 1)
player2 = Player(player2_x, player2_y, 100, 100, "Icon2.png", 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, False, player2_y, 2)

while not game_over:

    player1.move()
    player2.move()

    player1.jump(gravity)
    player2.jump(gravity)

    player1.update()
    player2.update()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(player1.icon, (player1.x, player1.y))
    screen.blit(player2.icon, (player2.x, player2.y))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You need to move your event processing loop out of the player class and into the main loop. At the moment `player1.move()` is consuming all events on every iteration

Comment: Perhaps inspecting pygame.key.get_pressed would be better here? You would not have to look for keyup/down events. I think at the moment if any keyup event happens you stop all movement https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed

Comment: @Klukinchikendo `pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to separate the event from the class, so if you create a eventhandler class/function which calls the correct member function for the player will resolve this problem. As well the event consuming problem since only this event handler class has to be consume the events.

like :

```
def Event_handler():
   if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key == ord("w"):
           player_1.up()                    
       elif event.key == ord("s"):
           player_1.down()
```

and so on for the other inputs